# Why does the size of my binary depend on the size of my array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, mingw, stdarray

I've recently stumbled upon a very strange code bloat effect that I really cannot explain to myself... The following is a working minimal example:

```
#include <array>

const int SIZE = 4000000;

struct Foo
{
    static Foo& GetInstance()
    {
        static Foo instance;
        return instance;
    }

    std::array<float, SIZE> Bar;
};

int main()
{
    Foo::GetInstance().Bar[0] = 1.0f;
    return 0;
}
```

The resulting binary (built with GCC MinGW 4.9.2 x86_64 posix sjlj) is **15.28 MB** in size. However if you set e.g. `SIZE = 1` you get a **17 KB** binary instead.

So why does the size of the binary depend on the size of the array here? Apparently, the effect is caused by the struct being a Singleton. Yet I still don't see any plausible reasoning why the compiler would bloat the binary. Thanks for your help!

(Tested with and without optimization and with the `-std=c++11` flag only. Btw this also happens with C-style arrays...)

Comment: Because objects with static storage duration are often stored in a special section of the executable (that is implementation-dependent, of course). Hence, the larger your object, the larger that section.

Comment: Yes, singleton. Static var values are stored in the program file, and apparently GCC doesn´t care that most values are 0. Other than that, a 4Mio static array looks wrong. Such a large stack array isn´t even possible (usual systems+settings), so just don´t make such arrays without dynamic stuff.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: But zero-initialised objects are usually not stored in the executable, since that's very wasteful; they're given an entry in a `.bss` section so they can be initialised at runtime. Presumably, this particular compiler doesn't do that for local static variables for some reason.

Comment: FWIW, the code gives me a 8kb executable on Linux. It must be a quirk of MinGW. I suggest you stop trying to use Windows, no good ever came from that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour this has nothing to do with (your subjective opinion on)  windows ! With MSVC13 I have an executable of 10kb, using the native toolchain.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Blame your fellow GNUs

Comment: @christope: it certainly appears to have everything to do with the use of this toolchain on Windows. I merely suggested my favoured approach to dealing with problems involving Windows. Other approaches are, of course, possible if you have some reason for using that platform.

Answer (score 6):

> *"Apparently, the effect is caused by the struct being a Singleton. Yet I still don't see any plausible reasoning why the compiler would bloat the binary. "*

Yes, your observation is correct. Your singleton instance has *static storage duration*. The fact that the size of the array determines your binary code size, is because all of the initialization for your singleton object is done at compile time and probably goes to the `.text` section.

But that's all dependent on the currently used compiler implementation, and optimization levels.